# Lambda function is not updated even after successful execution of CodeBuild Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

Have recently setup a basic CodePipeline on AWS (following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html) which is triggered when there is a new commit on the CodeCommit repository.

But even though after successful execution of the pipeline the lambda function is not updated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 12
  build:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - export BUCKET=xx-test
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $BUCKET --output-template-file outputtemplate.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template.yml
    - outputtemplate.yml
```

My template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  helloWorld
  API Gateway connectivity helloWorld
  
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

Is there any additional configuration that need to be done?

Comment: Please review 'outputtemplate.yml' generated by codebuild. If the CodeUri under the resource ' AWS::Serverless::Function' is a static s3 path (like a path to zip file), then CloudFormation may not be able to "detect" a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've posted, it seems that your last action is `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE`? If so this would explain why there are no updates to your lambda function. Namely, this only creates a changeset, but **doesn't not execute it**. It other words, it does not apply it.

You need to add new action after `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE` action, which is called `CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE`. This action will take the changes created by the `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE`, and actually apply it to your stack.

How to add such an action is described in [Complete the deployment stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html#create-pipeline2) of the tutorial you've provided:

> Change sets let you preview the changes that are made before making them, and add approval stages. Add a second action that **executes the change set to complete the deployment**.

Comment: Thanks Marcin that was the issue, it was in parallel stage.